# PHP Ratchet and WebRTC

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, streaming, webrtc

I am trying to develop streaming webrtc on a PHP website.

I want to establish streaming peer to peer with webrtc.

I know webrtc works fine on node and socket to make all the configuration to stablish webrtc connection.

Can I use Ratchet and PHP in place of node and socket?

Does Ratchet support https?

Comment: https yes . You will need signaling , very simply just send msg everybody on receive candidate. Clients do everything .For config ratchet to work with php session you will need more research i cant help you in that point.

Answer (score 8):

Almost all the tutorials says WebRTC is simple, but at the same time they keep repeating only the same [webrtc.org](https://webrtc.org/start/) basic examples and using almost only Node.js.

I found [this](https://github.com/bndr/webRTC-php) nice early WebRTC+PHP GitHub project that codes a simple signaling server using PHP and MySQL (although it could be replace by a text file). I think it could be useful to you. Is outdated, last change was 6 years ago, but I could explain you the changes in the code needed to run it using PHP 7 and the last Firefox and Chrome versions.

I'm planning to share a fork when I could achieve to code a multiple (not a fixed number) users version. But the lack of examples make it harder.

Comment: How can I help to update the code and add video functionalities?

Comment: @Junior, [this article](https://medium.com/@amirsanni/building-a-text-audio-and-video-chat-web-app-using-webrtc-and-ratchet-45863446e79a) (code included) explains how to build a text, audio and video chat web app using webRTC and Ratchet (PHP). I guess it can be useful to you, unless you are looking to code it in the simplest way just to learn it as I do.

Comment: Hi @leopoldo-sanczyk. I found the project you mentioned and gave some contribuitions and fixes there. If someone want a Live Demo, can use https://phpvideochat.lupahosting.com.br/. Thank's the tip

Answer (score 3):

So you want to develop a streaming webrtc example on a PHP website.

If you use shared hosting, it is going to be difficult with PHP because then you do not have commandline access on the server, which you need for a WebSocket implementation. Then you can use my project at https://github.com/nielsbaloe/webrtc-php to do WebRtc without websockets with SSE (ServerSideEvents). Works great for say less than hundred users.

If you are not on shared hosting, then you can use any PHP package which supports websocket, like Ratchet. However, that is what nobody does these days. You can also switch to using node.js and have a signalling server with less than 10 lines of code.

Comment: have you manage to work with ratchet? I am also looking for a webrtc solution using ratchet

Comment: This isn't difficult with PHP over HTTP,  just timely and inefficient. Caller will begin by sending SDP description and ice candidates to server via ajax. Caller will then start to poll the server for responses from answerer. Answerer will see somebody is trying to call them (receiving callers SDP and ICE) and send their own SDP description and ice candidates to server and begin polling for additional ICE candidates caller might send. When caller's poll responds with answers initial SDP and ICE it will poll for any additional ice candidates from answerer and so on until connection established

Answer (score 2):

Yes, WebRTC works well with PHP hosts. The  important fact here is that practically anything can be used as a signalling server. You can literally write SDP descriptions and ICE candidates down on paper and send them back and forth using homing pidgins. But where PHP is involved, yes, Ratchet, Workerman, Swoole etc can each be used for creating signalling servers. Most WebRTC gateways also have PHP friendly plugins allowing PHP hosts to play a more active roll in establishing connections between peers when conference servers, SFUs, MCUs etc are thrown into the mix.

Comment: I would love an example of that. Is there an example where two separate web clients get the other's through a textarea box?

Comment: @Altimus Prime - what do you mean? First, the value of each textarea can be sent between the two clients via websocket, or ajax if each client continually checks if the other has sent their own textarea value. If you mean once connected over WebRTC this would be done p2p using WebRTC datachannels.

Comment: What I was trying to ask: Suppose that someone sent me their SDP information in an email and I pasted it into a text area, and I did the same for them and we were able to connect via WebRTC. Is there some demo or example of how to do just that without a signaling server at all?